# UICollectionViewCell how to stop some process in other cells using active one

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have collection view with 3 cells. Each cell contains one button. When I tap on the button in the first cell it starts animate itself. So my gaol is to dismiss animation in the current button if I tap for example on the button in the second/3rd cell and vice verse.

What is the better way to do it. I suppose to store maybe all buttons in some array and then check which one is active now and then switch off it and switch on other.

But maybe it's better to create some cell builder or smth like that.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(VAXSettingsModeCell.reusableCellIdentifier(), forIndexPath: indexPath) as! VAXSettingsModeCell
    cell.delegate = self
    let title = modesStrings[indexPath.row]
    cell.AnimatableButton.setTitle(title, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store IndexPath of animated cell inside your ViewController

```
@interface MyViewController: ViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *animatedCellIndexPath;
@end
```

When user tap the button inside cell you can save this cell's indexPath and stop animations for all visible cells and then start animation for tapped cell.

```
- (void)buttonTappedForCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)tappedCell {
  self.animatedCellIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:tappedCell];
  for (UITableViewCell *cell in [self.collectionView visibleCells]) {
    [cell setAnimating:NO];
  }
  [tappedCell setAnimating:YES];
}
```

And for every new cell you can check if that cell must be animated (for example if user scrolls collection view)

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  cell = ...
  [cell setAnimating:indexPath == self.animatedCellIndexPath];
  return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `UICollectionViewCell` reference on the animating cell and when you press on other cells (`didSelectCell`..) stop the animation on that cell. When you animating other cell change the reference to the animating cell. Have in mind that if you are using reuseIdentifier and the animating cell is not showing in the screen then the `UICollectionView` will reuse it and you might see the animating cell on the wrong position. In that case your solution with array will be the ideal but you have to track that the animating cell is not showing in the screen (or in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` stop the animation on each cell and then check if the currentIndex path has to animate and start animating).

**Update**
You can do it without array. Just set an `NSInteger activeCellIndex=indexPath.row` and check that one.